# iOS - Execute precompiled app from a server

Tags: objective-c, ios, compilation, runtime

I'm looking for executing a .xib (with its own controllers and libraries) precompiled on a server, downloading it on runtime.
Is it possible?

Thanks!

EDIT:

So could somebody give me an example of a program that uses NSBundle that executes other app?
And how do I create the bundled application?

Comment: Possible as in 'allowed' or technically possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can import a xib into the application's bundle at run-time (which you would have to in order for this to happen). Others may know more and correct me!

Comment: Actually you can, but as Chris explained - if one wants to publish apps on the AppStore, such functionality is prohibited (for security reasons, I imagine). See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/CFNSBundle.html

Comment: I've tryied to do it, through the documentation, but there isn't any example code. I'm so newbie in cocoa/touch, but I need achieve it! Could you explain me in a easy way? I'm not pretending to get it to apple store. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple of ways you could try to do this, but are you aiming to get it in to the store?

This is expressly prohibited by Apple Developer Guidelines.

Comment: Hey Chris, can you explain that ways you have just say? I'm not trying to get it to apple store, only for internal business usage.
Thanks!

Comment: Hey, the method that @Caleb mentioned will work fine. As he mentioned, you won't be able to dynamically link any code associated with those XIBs, but you could do something like change the nib used for inWithNib: on a Class that's already in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

A .xib file is just a data file, so there shouldn't be any problem loading one that's outside your app's bundle. I can't say I've ever tried it, but as long as it's in a bundle, you should be able to:

1. Create an instance of NSBundle using the path to the bundle containing the .xib you want to load. See `+[NSBundle bundleWithPath:]` for that.
2. Load the .xib using the bundle you created in the previous step with any of the normal .xib-loading methods, such as `-[UIViewController initWithNibNamed:bundle:]` or `+[UINib nibWithNibName:bundle:]`.

> with it's own controllers and libraries

That part won't work. iOS doesn't allow dynamic linking to frameworks other than the ones provided by the system, so there's no way to load your code. If you can build all the code you need into your app, though, you should still be able to use downloaded .xib's as described above. That would let you do things like update the way your views are laid out or what targets and actions your controls are connected to.